# Best Practive for ngRoute, ng-view, and code duplication

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngroute

The Angular API Reference for `ngRoute` provides this [example](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route#example). Notice that chapter.html contains duplicated code from book.html.

If a use case requires the `$route` functionality, what would be the proper way to implement this example? I would want to use `ng-include` for both `book.html` and `chapter.html` to remove the duplication, but then using `$route` is out of the picture, correct?

Answer (score 1):

> but then using $route is out of the picture, correct?

$route is only being used to display what the values of the parameters are. For you this would not be part of the actual application I assume? See this part:

```
  <pre>$location.path() = {{$location.path()}}</pre>
  <pre>$route.current.templateUrl = {{$route.current.templateUrl}}</pre>
  <pre>$route.current.params = {{$route.current.params}}</pre>
  <pre>$route.current.scope.name = {{$route.current.scope.name}}</pre>
  <pre>$routeParams = {{$routeParams}}</pre>
```

Or do you mean that you wouldn't use the routing system altogether? I would sa that you can leave this as is. The code that is being loaded by the different routes is for a book:

```
controller: {{name}}<br />
Book Id: {{params.bookId}}<br />
```

And for a chapter:

```
controller: {{name}}<br />
Book Id: {{params.bookId}}<br />
Chapter Id: {{params.chapterId}}
```

This means that you could include the 'book.html' in 'chapter.html' using ng-include. Or you could create a directive responsible for printing a book, and reuse this.

So that would become with ng-include:

```
<div ng-include='book.html'></div>
Chapter Id: {{params.chapterId}}
```

Or with a directive:

```
<my-book-directive></my-book-directive>
Chapter Id: {{params.chapterId}}
```

Comment: It is my understanding of directives that they are to ["include markers that attach a specific behaviour to that DOM element"](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive), so I wouldn't advocate that approach. +1 however because I didn't know we could nest partials. I was unsuccessful in giving that a try before, but I must have been doing something wrong. Thanks.